# Not being prompted for OAuth consent when logging into web application

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I am writing a SPA web app that is registered as an app in Azure AD. Everything was working fine most of the week; however, when I went to work on it today, I wasn't getting the expected results.

I deleted and recreated the app registration, hoping it would fix the issue, but it made things worse. When I navigate to the URL, I'm redirected to log in to Azure AD. That part works fine. Since I just created the app registration, I would expect to be taken to a page to consent to the application, but instead I'm redirected back to my application.

I check the app registration in Azure, and it does not have me listed as a user of the application.

Because of all of this, I can't acquire tokens to call external APIs (which I have registered in my app registration).

I'm not sure why I am running into this all of the sudden. Any thoughts on why the OAuth consent is being by-passed? I'm starting to wonder if MSFT is having services issues or not, but more than likely, the problem is on my end.

Suggestions on how to troubleshoot are also welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things you can do to give consent that will likely fix your app. From what it sounds like your app isn't consenting before ADAL.js you use acquireToken (which is a silent call and can't consent).

1. Go into the Azure Portal > Azure AD > the app you registered, then at the top hit `Grant Permissions`.  This is the equivalent of admin consent and will consent for all users in your tenant.
2. Run your app and hit login.  When you get redirected to the Azure AD sign in page, add to the url `&prompt=consent`, hit enter and reload the page w/ that parameter and sign in.  This will force the consent screen and consent for the current user. You can also append on the `prompt=admin_consent` if you're signing in w/ an admin account.

Comment: Life Saver! I'm not an admin, so my only option was to add `&prompt=consent` and it worked. It also answers another question I had around how to handle changing permissions in the future. I'll have to look into adal.js further to see if they have hooks already, if not, I may need to listen for this error and redirect back to login with the `prompt` query string parameter set. I would also like to know why this is now happening to me when it seemed to work fine earlier in the week.